# Dynamic icons import with material ui icons

Tags: material-ui

is there a way to import svg icons dynamicly based on a json file using [Material-ui Svg icons](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#svg-icons)?
Here's an example of my json file:

```
[
  {
    "name": "home",
    "icon": "Home",
    "title": "Home"
  },
  {
    "name": "business",
    "icon": "Business",
    "title": "Business"
  },
  {
    "name": "apartment",
    "icon": "Apartment",
    "title": "Apartment"
  }
]
```

I want to map this json to create a menu list with icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who need the same I've created a custom Icon component with a list of icons

```
import ApartmentIcon from '/path/to/icon';
import BusinessIcon from '/path/to/icon';
import HomeIcon from '/path/to/icon';

const IconList = {
  apartment: ApartmentIcon,
  business: BusinessIcon,
  home: HomeIcon,
}

const Icon = ({ icon, ...props }) => {
    const Component = Icons[icon];
    return <Component {...props} />;
};

export default Icon;
```

So I can import the Icon component and then map the json to get the icon

```
menuJson.map((menuItem) => <Icon icon={menuItem.name} />)
```

Feel free to reach out if you need help with another implementation

Answer (score 0):

// sample to your json:

```
const dynamicIcon: { [key: number]: React.ReactElement<SvgIconProps> } = {
  home: <Home />,
  business: <Business />,
  apartment: <Apartment />,
};
```

// code usage:

```
 <Box>
  { dynamicIcon['home'] }
 </Box>
```